# Form being shown to all users

Tags: php, html

I have my php setup so that only a logged in user, viewing their own profile can share something through a form I provide. You aren't supposed to see it if you are viewing another user's profile page, but for some reason it is still showing up. What could I be doing wrong?

```
<?php


if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $user_id= $_GET['id'];
}
else {
    $user_id= $_COOKIE['user_id'];
}

$dbc= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'beta');

$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id= '$user_id'";
$result= mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$data= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (!isset($_GET['user_id']) || ($_GET['user_id'] == $_COOKIE['user_id']))
{
echo "Share Something:";
?>

<form method="post" action="share.php">
<input type="text" name="story"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="share"/>
</form> 

<?php
}
echo '<a href="logout.php"> Logout </a></br><hr>';
echo $data['fname'] . " " . $data['lname'] . "</br><hr>";

$query2= "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id= '$user_id'";
$result= mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['story'] . "</br>";
}
}
else {
echo 'please <a href="login.html"> Login </a>!';
}

?>
```

Comment: Where is the logic that checks to see if it's the logged in user's page?

Answer (score 2):

one time you use `$user_id = $_GET['id'];` and in the if you use `$_GET['user_id']`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing from your if statement that the current users ID is taken from the cookie, and the user ID of the "page" is taken from the query string.

So try,

```
if (isset($_GET['user_id']) && ($_GET['user_id'] == $_COOKIE['user_id']))
```

That way you have to be on a "user page" that is yours to see the form.

You are also using `'id'` and `'user_id'` which is correct?